# Terraform 0.12 Creating ingress rules with template

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

I wonder if something like this could be used. I have functional code working, but as pods in kubernetes will grow up fast, I want to convert into templates. This is an example for the creation of each nginx ingress rule for each wordpress site pod.

Now, each pod has its wordpress ingress entry with:

```
resource "kubernetes_ingress" "ingress_nginx_siteA" {
  metadata {
    name        = "ingress-nginx-siteA"
    namespace   = "default"
    annotations = { "kubernetes.io/ingress.class" = "nginx", "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet" = "modsecurity_rules '\n SecRuleEngine On\n SecRequestBodyAccess On\n SecAuditEngine RelevantOnly\n SecAuditLogParts ABCIJDEFHZ\n SecAuditLog /var/log/modsec_audit.log\n SecRuleRemoveById 932140\n';\n", "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough" = "true" }
  }
  spec {
    tls {
      hosts       = ["siteA.test.com"]
      secret_name = "wildcard-test-com"
    }
    rule {
      host = "siteA.test.com"
      http {
        path {
          path = "/"
          backend {
            service_name = "siteA"
            service_port = "80"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now I want to split into **variables.tf** that contain the whole sites variables, a template file **rules.tpl** and the **main.tf** that orchestrate this stuff.

variables.tf:

```
variable "wordpress_site" {
  type = map(object({
    name        = string
    url         = string
    certificate = string
  }))
    default = {
    siteA = {
      name        = siteA
      url         = siteA.test.com
      certificate = wildcard-test-com
    }
    siteB = {
      name        = siteB
      url         = siteB.test.com
      certificate = wildcard-test-com
    }
  }
}
```

rules.tpl:

```
%{ for name in wordpress_site.name ~}
resource "kubernetes_ingress" "ingress_nginx_${name}" {
  metadata {
    name        = "ingress-nginx-${name}"
    namespace   = "default"
    annotations = { "kubernetes.io/ingress.class" = "nginx", "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet" = "modsecurity_rules '\n SecRuleEngine On\n SecRequestBodyAccess On\n SecAuditEngine RelevantOnly\n SecAuditLogParts ABCIJDEFHZ\n SecAuditLog /var/log/modsec_audit.log\n SecRuleRemoveById 932140\n';\n", "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough" = "true" }
  }
  spec {
    tls {
      hosts       = ["${wordpress_site.url}"]
      secret_name = "${wordpress_site.certificate}"
    }
    rule {
      host = "${wordpress_site.url}"
      http {
        path {
          path = "/"
          backend {
            service_name = "${name}"
            service_port = "80"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
%{ endfor ~}
```

and now, in main.tf, what is the best way in order to mix it all? I see that new functionalities are added in TF 0.12 like templatefile function, but didn't know at all if I can use it like:

main.tf:

```
templatefile(${path.module}/rules.tpl, ${module.var.wordpress_site})
```

Thanks all for your support!

Answer (score 0):

The `templatefile` function is for generating strings from a template, not for generating Terraform configuration. Although it would be possible to render your given template to produce a string containing Terraform configuration, Terraform would just see the result as a normal string, not as more configuration to be evaluated.

Instead, what we need to get the desired result is [resource `for_each`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html#for_each-multiple-resource-instances-defined-by-a-map-or-set-of-strings), which allows creating multiple instances from a single resource based on a map value.

```
resource "kubernetes_ingress" "nginx" {
  for_each = var.wordpress_site

  metadata {
    name        = "ingress-nginx-${each.value.name}"
    namespace   = "default"
    annotations = {
      "kubernetes.io/ingress.class" = "nginx"
      "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet" = <<-EOT
        modsecurity_rules '
         SecRuleEngine On
         SecRequestBodyAccess On
         SecAuditEngine RelevantOnly
         SecAuditLogParts ABCIJDEFHZ
         SecAuditLog /var/log/modsec_audit.log
         SecRuleRemoveById 932140
        ';
      EOT
      "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough" = "true"
    }
  }
  spec {
    tls {
      hosts       = [each.value.url]
      secret_name = each.value.certificate
    }
    rule {
      host = each.value.url
      http {
        path {
          path = "/"
          backend {
            service_name = each.value.name
            service_port = "80"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When a resource has `for_each` set, Terraform will evaluate the given argument to obtain a map, and will then create one instance of the resource for each element in that map, with each one identified by its corresponding map key. In this case, assuming the default value of `var.wordpress_site`, you'll get two instances with the following addresses:

- `kubernetes_ingress.nginx["siteA"]`
- `kubernetes_ingress.nginx["siteB"]`

Inside the `resource` block, references starting with `each.value` refer to the values from the map, which in this case are the objects describing each site.

Comment: Many thanks @martin-atkins ! I'll adapt the code and test it. I'll be back with results.